# Batch rename directories (delete suffix) in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, batch, cmd.exe

I have been trying to understand Windows batch scripts but the syntax is so very different to modern programming languages that I simply cannot get what I want to do to work. I've also tried googling this and checked SO/SU to no avail.

I have a large number of folders in another folder ("C:\Users\me\Desktop\Delete") that are the contents of downloaded web pages. The format is:

```
thisIsTheWebPageName_files
thisIsTheWebPageName.html
```

What I'd like to do in a batch file (note: standard CMD .bat file - not PowerShell) is to iterate over all folders, rename them by simply removing the "_files" suffix, then deleting the associated .html file. I am sure an expert can probably do this in one line - can anyone help?

Comment: If you prefer a modern programming language, any reason you specifically don't want to use one? PowerShell is pretty standard in Windows 10 now, and it has regexes and pretty much everything that you'd also find in C#?

Comment: @user1686 Thanks for your question. It's because I'd like to integrate this code into an existing batch file that I already use to perform other file/directory functions. I'd hate to port the whole thing over to PowerShell if the solution to this problem is only 1 or 2 well-written lines of code.

Comment: Unfortunately, "well-written" in Cmd is still going to be about the same level as "cat walking across keyboard"... It's doable, sure, but I think porting the entire script would be a worthwhile investment.

Comment: @Arj then why don't just call `powershell` from cmd? It's easier to do such things in powershell

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over all files or directories:

```
for %%i in (*.html) do ...

for /d %%i in (*_files) do ...
```

Note: In .bat scripts you must use `%%` for the iterator variable, while the interactive shell uses only a single `%`.

Remove a file extension (only works with iterators, not variables):

```
%~ni, %~xi

for %%f in (*.html) do echo %%~nf_files
```

Replace a substring (only works with named variables, not iterator):

```
%var:old=new%

ren "%dir%" "%dir:_files=%"
```

Slice a string (only works with named variables):

```
%var:~begin,end%

ren "%dir%" "%dir:~0,-6%"
```

> iterate over all folders, rename them by simply removing the "_files" suffix, then deleting the associated .html file

Doing two things at once within the same `for` loop is *possible*, but makes the usage of named variables quite annoying, as they're expanded at read time, not at call time. (And we need named variables to remove the "_files" suffix.)

It might be easier to call a subroutine instead:

```
for /d %%d in (*_files) do call :tidy "%%~d"
goto :eof

:tidy
set "dirname=%~1"
echo Would run: ren "%dirname%" "%dirname:~0,-6%"
echo Would run: del "%dirname:~0,-6%.html"
goto :eof
```

But if every single `*.html` file has a corresponding _files directory and vice versa, you could iterate over the files instead:

```
for %%i in (*.html) do echo ren "%%~ni_files" "%%~ni" && echo del "%%~i"
```

(I *think* the `&&` works as intended here. I might do it in two steps instead.)

```
for %%i in (*.html) do echo ren "%%~ni_files" "%%~ni"
del *.html
```

Comment: things like dealing with the arcane feature set of Cmd are what can tip a question over between "interesting enough to post a whole answer on this" versus "we're not a script-writing service and this is covered in bash's/python's/etc. beginner tutorial"

Comment: Thank you so much @user1686! I didn't even know you could add subroutines in batch files. That worked perfectly!